# how to declare a temp variable and a buffer to perform Bitwise operations over a string in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator, mips64

I am working on an assignment for my Assembly language class, and I am stuck in the bitwise operations, I got the first character without any problem, but while I am keep going within the loop, the temporary var that I set is not doing what it suppose to, and think it all happens in this set of instructions:

```
addi $t2, $t2, -5   # bits -=5
 srlv $t3, $t0, $t2 #newTempVar = buffer >> bits
 and $t4,$t3,0x1F   #temp = newTempVar & 0x1F

 la $s0, chars      #load the address of the first element of string: chars
 addu  $s0,$s0,$t4  #get the character in the possition $t4 
 lb $a0, ($s0)      #load the character in memory
 li $v0, 11         #function print character             
 syscall
 move $t4, $0
```

This is the whole code:

```
.data
      chars:    .ascii "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ .,!-'"
       msg1:    .word 0x93EA9646, 0xCDE50442, 0x34D29306, 0xD1F33720
    msg1end:    .word 0x56033D01, 0x394D963B, 0xDE7BEFA4
     msglen:   .word 16   

.text
   .globl main

main:   

    la $s1, msg1
    lbu $s0, ($s1)
    #la $s2, msg1end
    addu $s2,$s0,16
    #la $t0, buffer     
    li $t0, 0   #set buffer = 0

    addi $t1, $t1, 0    #index
    addi $t2, $t2, 0    #bits
    lw $t5, ($s1)       #*msg1

while:
    bgt $t5,$s2,endwhile
    if: 
      bgt $t2, 5,endif

      addi $s1,$s1, 4   # next element in the array
      addi $t1, $t1, 1  #increment the index
      lw $t5, ($s1)     #msg1

      move $t4, $t5     #temp = nextbyte++

      sll $t3, $t0,8    # newTemp = buffer << 8
      or $t0, $t3, $t4  # buffer = newTemp | temp
      addi $t2, $t2, 8
      move $t4, $0

    endif:
      addi $t2, $t2, -5     # bits -=5
      srlv $t3, $t0, $t2    #newTempVar = buffer >> bits
      and $t4,$t3,0x1F      #temp = newTempVar & 0x1F

      la $s0, chars     #load the address of the first element of string: chars
      addu  $s0,$s0,$t4 #get the character in the possition $t4 
      lb $a0, ($s0)     #load the character in memory
      li $v0, 11         #function print character             
      syscall
      move $t4, $0
      j while         #jump back to the while loop

endwhile:
    li,$v0,10
    syscall
```

I really appreciate the help

Comment: *not doing what it suppose to* - What *is* it supposed to do?  It's good that you narrowed down a [mcve] to a small block of code that you can see with the debugger isn't doing what you want.  That snippet appears to match its comments, but it's weird so IDK what you want it to be doing.  I think maybe extracting 5-bit fields that were packed into a register, and using them as table indices?  So printing a number in base 32 with letters and symbols as digits.  A [mcve] also has to show what actually happens vs. what you want to happen.  Copy/paste some example values from the debugger.

Comment: The code supposed to iterate through the array of hex values and perform bitwise operations, then after getting an index to find a value within the "chars" array and print it, for at the end have a complete sentence, what happened is that I found the first value without any problem, but the second value is not the value expected, I know that because I had the code in c++ and I perform the bitwise operation and I see the results that are supposed to show. Thanks

Comment: [edit] your question to say that, including a specific example.  The actual wrong output value is often a hint to what went wrong.  Looking at values to help in finding mistakes is why debuggers exist.  Debugging is all about details but you're barely giving any about what wrong result is printed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I got it solved, it was a matter of loading bytes instead of words, therefore I am going to post the code, after May 15th, that way other people in my class could get to the right answer by themselves. It is hard work but it worth it.